# Difference between two dates in excel in mmddyy format

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, difference

I need to find difference between two dates in excel which are in mmddyy format
eg:
A1 = 070114
B1 = 063015

Need to find B1-A1 in number of days

Comment: I guess you could convert your string to date using `=DATE(RIGHT(A2,2)+2000,LEFT(A2,2),MID(A2,3,2))`. Once you have correct date formats, you simply subtract the two

Comment: thanks, that works

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(B1,5,0,"/"),3,0,"/")-REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,5,0,"/"),3,0,"/")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Prefer solution by @ScottCraner but already had this written out so:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(B1,2)+2000,LEFT(B1,2),MID(B1,3,2)) - DATE(RIGHT(A1,2)+2000,LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,3,2))
```

---

Comment: Nice thing about Scott's is that it handles dates in the 20th century.

Comment: Which is def why I noted it as preferred :)

Comment: The one drawback to mine is that it assumes `mm/dd/yy` as the local setting for date, where this one make no assumption of the local settings.

Answer (score 2):

If your windows regional settings are MDY (same order) then:

```
=TEXT(B1,"00\/00\/00")-TEXT(A1,"00\/00\/00")
```

If your wrs are different, then you'll need to convert the date values to real dates first.

[image]